# What does * mean in a function definition?

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, arguments

I have code like this

```
def my_pow(x=3, *, y=2):
    return x**y
my_pow(4,4)
```

I know what `*args` and `**kwargs` mean, but have no idea what `*` means between positional arguments.

Why `my_pow(4,4)` doesn't work? Whereas all variants below do.

```
my_pow(4,y = 4)
my_pow(x = 4)
my_pow(y = 4)
my_pow(4)
```

Answer (score 1):

`*` marks that arguments after it in the function's definition are keyword-only. It was [introduced in Python 3.0](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3102/).

The reason `pow(4, 4)` does not work is because of that symbol. Only `pow(x=4, y=4)` or `pow(4, y=4)` will work.

Comment: ``*`` was not introduced in Python 3.8. You might be thinking of ``/``.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi True, it was introduced in Python 3.0. I'll edit the answer so it doesn't mislead.